# Create multiple sails models on single request

Tags: sails.js

I'm uploading a CSV file to the sails app. At this point it should do two things:

1. the UploadController should store the unaltered uploaded file using the UploadModel
2. the UploadController should parse the file and store each entry in the EntryModel

My first thought was I could do something like

```
entries = parse(data);
foreach(entry in entries) {
    sails.models.entry.create(entry);
}
```

but this approach silently fails.

Is there a proper way to handle this sort of scenario?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call `.create` with an array of objects to create multiple models; this is [referred to in the documentation for `.create()`](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/waterline/models/create.html?q=parameters).  So:

```
sails.models.entry.create(entries).exec(...);
```

should work fine.

Comment: Hey sgress454, since you mentioned the documentation, could it be that the sailsjs.org url structure recently got changed? I'm asking because google search results are pointing to urls that redirect to [http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts). One example is [http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/models](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/models)

Comment: apparently the behavior if one of the entries throws a validation error isnt defined, or is it?